# how to change next activity background when i press button in current activity

Tags: java, javascript, android

i want to change the background for next activity when i press a button in my current activity & i have 32 buttons and all will go to same activity but i want to change the back ground of it according to button prees so it will change 32 times I try this but it doesn't work

```
buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","fattetl3bet");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back1);


            }   
     });

     buttons[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sikkarwasat");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back254);


            }   
     });

     buttons[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","superfamily");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2978);


            }   
     });

     buttons[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","wiladaminalkhasira1");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back27);


            }   
     });

     buttons[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","wiladaminalkhasira2");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back280);


            }   
     });

     buttons[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","wiladaminalkhasira3");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back278);
                }   
     });

     buttons[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","zamanlbarghout1");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back278);
                }   
     });

     buttons[7].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","zamanlbarghout2");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back278);
                }   
     });

     buttons[8].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","ta7ounalchar1");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2896);
                }   
     });

     buttons[9].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","ta7ounalchar2");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back287);
                }   
     });

     buttons[10].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sar5troo7");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2879);
                }   
     });
     buttons[11].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sabaya1");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2789);
                }   
     });
     buttons[12].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sabaya2");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back234);
                }   
     });
     buttons[13].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sabaya3");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2435);
                }   
     });
     buttons[14].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sabaya4");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2345);
                }   
     });
     buttons[15].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sabaya5");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2435);
                }   
     });
     buttons[16].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","sana3oud");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2345);
                }   
     });
     buttons[17].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","ta7tasama2alwatan");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2435);
                }   
     });
     buttons[18].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","natrin");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back26546);
                }   
     });
     buttons[19].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","7oudoudchakika");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2546);
                }   
     });
     buttons[20].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","yasmin3atik");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2546);
                }   
     });
     buttons[21].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","znoodelset");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2546);
                }   
     });
     buttons[22].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Sori.this,listnameseries.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("namemovies","l3btmoot");
                startActivity(myIntent);
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back25464);
                }   
     });
```

Comment: Why are you setting the background resource of buttons[0] if you need to change the background resource for an instance of "Sori"? Why not send the color using myIntent.putExtra and then handle it upon activity initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an extra to your intent, for example a resource id

```
myIntent.putExtra("resource_id", R.color.myPreferedBackground);
```

then in the next activity in onCreate():

```
int bg = getIntent.getIntExtra("resource_id");
myLayout.setBackgroundResource(bg);
```

Comment: resourse id for th background or for activity ?

Comment: myLayout is the wrapping layout of your Activity.

Comment: In the xml layout file of your activity, give an id to the outer layout that wraps everything. Then in your Activity (if it's a linear layout): myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

Comment: it's just a key, just a name, you can name it whatever you want. But it has to be the same in putExtra(...) as in getIntExtra(...)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the intent send the information regarding the color to next activity.

In next activity onCreate change the color based on information.

Comment: I'd imagine op was expecting you'd who them how!